# Regular Expression for Comma separated 8 digit length

Tags: regex

Please provide me a Regular Expression for 8 digit length comma separated Numerics

12345678,
74125874, 56432141 
,98526314,

45126325

^[0-9]{8}+(\n\r)*(?:,[0-9]{8}+)*$

I am trying to use this Regex, it working only if we Enter the Entire Comma Separated 8 digit length in one line , if we Press new Line the above Regex is not working

Regards
Ravi

Comment: This post doesn't show any research effort. Stack Overflow isn't the place to ask "Please do this for me" type questions.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285733/should-give-me-a-regex-that-does-x-questions-be-closed

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. **You start it, and then we help. We don't write it for you.** Show us the actual code that you've tried, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
^\d{8}(?:,\d{8})*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sZ1lI9/1)

Comment: Hi Anubhava, 
its failing for multiline case , can help me on this ?
12345678,
12345678

12345789

Comment: Is there a space after comma also? You can try: `\b\d{8}(?:, *\d{8})*\b`